# Android 9: OpenVPN Per App

Tags: 9.0-pie, vpn, openvpn

First: this question is not a duplicate of:

1. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29137358/9190065): I don't want to use SOCKS, and I am not asking about Lollipop.
2. [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/197656/177973): No answer, and different use case
3. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25282065/9190065): I don't have time to develop my own application.

My goal: to find a way to force all internet traffic (including cellular ie LTE) into my OpenVPN server, except for apps on a whitelist. Whitelisted apps either connect to a second VPN or SOCKS proxy (option preferred), or not be connected to a tunnel at all (a "normal" connection).

For example, try out the ProtonVPN application (which, by the way, I recommend). There is an option to whitelist apps from the VPN. This is what I want, but for my own server.

Root is definitely not preferred, but if it's the only option, then I guess I'll accept it. Multiple profiles are also not preferred, but if it allows some apps to be over VPN and others not, then I will also accept that (but I would like system apps to be blocked in that case).

Thank you.

Comment: I have been using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.colucciweb.vpnclientpro with my OpenVPN server. With root you can manually filter UIDs in routing table. [Edited by Firelord]

Answer (score 2):

How about "OpenVPN for Android" made by schwabe.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn
https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn

It has per app connection setting by whitelist or blacklist, though it doesn't support second VPN or SOCKS proxy for the excepted apps.